# Unit Testing on a Repository with Generic Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, repository

Let's say I have a Generic Repository class along the lines of the following:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IObjectSet<T> source;
    public Repository(IUnitOfWork transactionHandler) 
    {
        source = transactionHandler.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return source.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        source.AddObject(entity);
    }
    //blah blah other methods
}
```

I am having trouble wrapping my mind around how (or even if?) I would unit test this.
Visual Studio generates a combo of tests that I can understand for the above implementation of GetAll

```
public void GetAllTest()
{
    GetAllTestHelper<SomeExpectedType>();//expect this to pass
    try 
    {
        GetAllTestHelper<SomeUnexpectedType>();//expect this to throw exception
    }
    //catch exception - check it is expected type etc. 
}

public void GetAllTestHelper<T>() where T : class
{
     IUnitOfWork transactionHandler = IUnitOfWorkFactory.GetUnitOfWork();
     Repository<T> target = new Repository<T>(transactionHandler);

     IQueryable<T> actual = target.GetAll();

     Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(IQueryable<T>));
}
```

The idea being - I can prove that calling this method returns an IQueryable of type T. I can also prove that it throws an InvalidOperationException for a type that an IObjectSet cannot be generated for (also required/desired).

For the Add method I am going round in circles.

For the 'why' - why have a test - I think I want to prove that I can add a type of T to the repository and then prove it has been added to the DB.

For the 'how' - using the VS default as above, I get something along the lines of

```
public void AddTest()
{    
    AddTestHelper<SomeExpectedType>();
}

public void AddTestHelper<T>() where T : class
{
    IUnitOfWork transactionHandler = UnitTestHelper.GetUnitOfWork();
    Repository<T> target = new Repository<T>(transactionHandler);

    T entity = default(T);

    target.Add(entity);//throws exception - value cannot be null
}
```

So my question is 
a) how would you unit test this repository?
or possibly
b) *would* you test this repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) how would you unit test this repository?

A mock framework such as [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) or [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) could simplify the task of unit testing this class. It would be used to mock the `IUnitOfWork` interface that is passed to the constructor of the repository.

For example here's how a typical unit test of the `Add` method for this repository might look like using Rhino Mocks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Add_Should_Use_AddObject_On_Underlying_Source()
{
    // arrange
    var uofStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUnitOfWork>();
    var objectSet = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IObjectSet<string>>();
    uofStub.Stub(x => x.CreateObjectSet<string>()).Return(objectSet);
    var sut = new Repository<string>(uofStub);
    var entity = "foo bar";

    // act
    sut.Add(entity);

    // assert
    objectSet.AssertWasCalled(x => x.AddObject(entity));
}
```

As far as the automatic combo of tests generated by Visual Studio are concerned IMHO that's probably one of the most useless ever feature in VS.

> b) would you test this repository?

Yes, absolutely.